# How to hide my application but not close/finish it

Tags: android

I would like to let user to leave my application by hiding it but not finishing it.

I could call finish() in my main activity, but it takes some time to do that. It's not good for user experience, therefore a better choice might be to hide it. Just I don't know how to achieve it.

Thanks for all the answer.

---

I am not trying to do something in the background, because I already have a service.

In my application, user might press an button to close my main activity. However, it take a little time to do that. At least after 0.5 sec, then I'll see my application disappear on screen.

However, if I press home key. My application is disappear immediately, so it's the effect I need.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. This already happens when a user clicks the home button or starts another activity.

Comment: Yes your Application is closed when the user closes it (through a task killer or something). Or do you want to do things in background? Then you maybe need a Service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to move your activity in the background

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: When should I call it, and should I call finish after it? Thanks

Comment: If you have a button onClick event, simply put the code in there. It should do exactly what press on Home button does.

Comment: Thanks but if I only call it, my app is not hide/close. But I could call the finish() after it, my app will become hiding in the background but not close. Is that the correct method?

Comment: Basically Android should close your app when it needs memory. I never called finish() after it, ad I never close my apps, but you can give it a try. You can override onDestroy on your activity and see if it gets executed after sent to background and called finish().

Answer (score 0):

If you need your app to continue running in the background, spawn the background code in a Service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just want to end it fast. So I want to hide it but now close it. I have an service in my application already.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice here is simply to start looking at all of the garbage collection the app has to do and make sure you only keep things (connections, etc) open for as long as absolutely necessary.

Point is to limit the amount of stuff the app has to do to finally shut down.