# How to use saved instance state and restore instance state with spinners in in Android?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner in my activity with a list of options,

When the user selects an option, I have used OnItemSelected adapter to get the position value of the selected option and within that i have added some If Else Statements. The If statement, actually generates a random string from the predefined database and displays on TextView.

Now i will be switching back to another activity and again come back to this activity. Now the problem is by default the first option of the spinner is only selected, I need to update with the last selected option of the user and when the activity starts again that option's functions must be run.

I did some searches too and found that this can be done by using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` now :

- How do I use these two and where should i put them, inside the onItemSelected(adapter) or Outside?
- How do I update(or store) the new position value selected by the user to the random generated code?

For clarity please check my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_scheduledactivity);

    /**displayed when the activity is launched (this should be 
    updated with the user selected option)**/
    Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.normal); 
    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(q);

    //initiating the spinner
      Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner);
      s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
 if (pos == 1){

     //displayed on the time when user selects the option
     Resources res = getResources();
     myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.hardships); 
     String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
     tv.setText(q);

     }

else {
    //do nothing
     }
```

**EDITED QUESTION:**

I have edited the question for more clarity. Basically what I am trying to do is, I want to save the position selected by they user, with the spinner. When the user clicks "Thankyou" `Button` the activity will finish and will start after few minutes called by a Broadcast receiver from a different class. When the activity starts again the last selected option (previous activity) of the user must be as default in this activity.

I think if you look at the code the problem is in save and restore instance state.

**Please have a look at my code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyScheduledActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    protected int mPos;
  protected String mSelection;
  String situation[] = {"Normal","Hardship","Sadness","Exam"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_scheduledactivity);


    if (mPos == 0) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.normal); 
    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(q);
    }

        //selection of the spinner
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner);

        // Application of the Array to the Spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, situation);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                    MyScheduledActivity.this.mPos = pos;
                    MyScheduledActivity.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                    //display toast                     
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The Situation is " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (mPos == 0){

                        Resources res = getResources();
                        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.hardships); 
                        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                        tv.setText(q);

                    }

                    if (mPos == 1){

                        Resources res = getResources();
                        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.hardships); 
                        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                        tv.setText(q);

                    }

                    else {
                        //do nothing
                         }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                //do something else
                    return;
                }
                });


    //dismiss button - Thank You
    Button buttonDismiss = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

    buttonDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }});

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putStringArray(mSelection, situation);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    situation = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("mSelection");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


}
```

[This is how the activity looks](http://www.flickr.com/photos/58646431@N02/6001239313/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your present Activity override a method called `onSaveInstanceState()` and put your data in bundle.

and override another method `onRestoreInstanceState()` and get those values from the bundle....

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still confused, sorry - im just a beginner. Please can you tell me where do I override the method ? before the On create(bundle) or after that?

* I have saved the user selection of the spinner like this: 

'MyScheduledActivity.this.mPos = pos; MyScheduledActivity.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();'

Now how do i store this data to the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)

Where do i Override onRestoreInstanceState() ?
Please note: This same activity will reload again for every paticular span of time. so the last spinner position should be saved.

Comment: I have re-edited the question now. Please can you check the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState I'm not able to get the result.

Comment: Hey, I finally got it. The problem was with - The dismiss button, which is actually shutting down the whole activity. instead of finish(); i used moveTaskToBack(true); ,  many thanks for this link. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184572/how-to-hide-my-application-but-not-close-finish-it)  God bless you. Happy Coding